# Dividing by 0 error / Sorry my sentences are in PT

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to this programming area, I'm taking a level 5 course and I'm learning java now.

I was trying to do some exercises at home, and now I'm trying to build an algorithm that let's the user choose (N) number of numbers, and then randomly display them and make the average of all the negatives, and the percentage of all the positive ones.

But there's this error with my counter, says it can't divide by 0, I even tried to initialize it as 1, and before I do the math I take -1 from him to come to it's original value, but it won't work.

Would appreciate some enlightnment here! Thanks alot!

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);      //ler stands for read 
        int nPos = 0, nNeg = 0, totalPos = 0, totalNeg = 0, contador = 1; 

//contador stands for counter 
        
        int N;
        double mediaNeg, percPos; //media stands for average 

        System.out.println("Insira o número de números que pretende inserir: "); 

// this print stands for insert the number of numbers you intend to insert
      
        N = ler.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i == N-1; i++){
            int num = random.nextInt(101) - 50;
            System.out.println(num);
            contador ++;
                if (num > 0){
                    nPos ++;
                    totalPos += num;
                }
                else if (num < 0){
                    nNeg ++;
                    totalNeg += num;
                }

        }

        contador = contador - 1;
        mediaNeg = (double) totalNeg / nNeg;
        percPos = (double) (totalPos / contador) * 100;

        System.out.println("Média dos negativos = " +mediaNeg);
        System.out.print("Percentagem dos positivos = " +percPos); 

//These two are supposed to show the average of the negative numbers, and the percentage of the positives. 


    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/